# How to override inline styles in AMP pages?

Tags: css, amp-html

I have an html body with some tags containing inline styles.Normally we could override inline with **!important** 
But as I need the page to be AMP valid , I couldn't use this method.
Any way to do this in AMP valid method ??

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** As you mentioned, in AMP [you can not use the `!important` style](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/style_pages/). Also you can only have [one style tag and it has to be in the `head` tag](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/).

You can override the general styles inline but not the other way around.

AMP needs to be able to enforce its element sizing rules, allowing the `!important` style would interfere with that.